# CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost - How to handle the network disconnect?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, networking, stream

We have created socket for streaming using the API "CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost".

```
func openStream() {
        if let aUrl = url {
            var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
            var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

            CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(
                kCFAllocatorDefault,
                aUrl as CFString,
                port!,
                &readStream,
                &writeStream)

            iStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
            oStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

            if ssl == true {
                let dict = [
                    kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: kCFBooleanFalse,     // allow self-signed certificate
                    kCFStreamSSLLevel: kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain    // don't understand, why there isn't a constant for version 1.2
                    ] as CFDictionary

                let sslSetRead = CFReadStreamSetProperty(iStream, CFStreamPropertyKey(kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings), dict)
                let sslSetWrite = CFWriteStreamSetProperty(oStream, CFStreamPropertyKey(kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings), dict)

                if sslSetRead == false || sslSetWrite == false {
                    //print("SSL Configuration Failed")
                }
            }
            commonStr = ""
            open(iStream)
            open(oStream)
            print("Open Stream")
        }
    }
```

Used the below delegate for getting events.

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
//        print("Stream : \(aStream.debugDescription) Event : \(eventCode.rawValue)")
        switch eventCode {
        case .endEncountered, .errorOccurred:
            streamError()
            break
        case .hasBytesAvailable:
            if let iStream = iStream {
                if aStream == iStream {
                    //read data
                    let bufferSize = 1024
                    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
                    var len: Int
                    while iStream.hasBytesAvailable {
                        len = iStream.read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
                        if len > 0 {
                            let output = Data.init(bytes: buffer, count: len)
                            bufferTokenize(output: output)
                        }else {
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    buffer.deallocate()
                }
            }
            break
        case .hasSpaceAvailable:
            if aStream == oStream! {
                streamReady()
            }
            break
        case .openCompleted:
            if aStream == oStream! {
                if let del = delegate {
                    del.connectionCompleted()
                }
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Other Supporting functions are

```
    func streamError() {
        stopStream()
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget:self)
        perform(#selector(callReconnect), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)
    }
    func open(_ stream: Stream?) {
        if let aStream = stream {
            aStream.delegate = self
            aStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.main, forMode: .common)
            aStream.open()
        }
    }
    func stopStream() {
        print("Stop Stream")
        close(iStream)
        close(oStream)
    }
    func close(_ stream: Stream?) {
        if nil != stream {
            stream?.close()
            stream?.remove(from: RunLoop.main, forMode: .common)
        }
    }
    func resetStream() {
        stopStream()
        openStream()
    }
```

**It is working fine for below steps**

1. Create connection - Open stream
2. get "openCompleted" event - then Create request
3. get "hasSpaceAvailable" event - then Send Request
4. get "hasBytesAvailable" event - then Handle Data
5. Disconnect connection from server for testing purpose
6. get "endEncountered" event - then Close the connection and Recreate the connection from step 1

**But the below scenario not working properly**

Follow the steps 1 - 4 then

5. Disconnect Internet connection for testing purpose - the event "hasBytesAvailable" stopped
6. Again reconnect the Internet connection within 30 seconds - now we get "hasBytesAvailable" event 
   But the reconnect time extent to 5 minute - We don't have any event, and don't get "endEncountered" or "errorOccurred" also. Then how to move to next stop.

Please Help, Thanks

Regards,
Elamvazhuthi K